# CellPrint to EquationNumbered using MaTeX

Tags: notebooks, matex

I'm writing an online book in a *Mathematica* template and would like to display equations using Szabolcs' wonderful *MaTeX* (LaTeX typesetting in *Mathematica*) because the readability is superior to the default from *Mathematica*.  Thus I use:

```
<<MaTeX`
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Magnification" -> 1.5];
```

This gives me the typography I seek:

```
MaTeX[HoldForm[Integrate[x^2, x] = x^3/3]]
```

[image: Equation]

I can then collapse the paired cells so that only the typeset equation is visible.

Fine.

However, I want such an equation to be in the `EquationNumbered` style, complete with automatic numbering.  Right now I have to hand select each such typeset cell and use the pull-down menu to change its style to EquationNumbered.

I thought the right approach would be:

```
CellPrint[EquationNumbered[
  MaTeX[HoldForm[Integrate[x^2, x] = x^3/3]]]]
```

but that does not work.

***Question***:  How do I programmatically create an `EquationNumbered` that nevertheless has the style of *MaTeX*?

Comment: It is also possible to edit the stylesheets to get the box ratios/fonts/layout nicer. I did that a few years back and it’s really paid off. I do all of my writing in Mathematica first now and then transfer to LaTeX for the second draft since it is much nicer/easier/less buggy to explore and edit iteratively in Mathematica for me

Comment: @b3m2a1:  If you have stylesheets available, or can point to one online, I'd love to see it.  I really need a style that mimics the *Mathematica* blue "reference" definitions of functions.  (I don't know *Mathematica* didn't include that in the as a Style.)

Answer (score 1):

Ah... I think I figured it out:

```
CellPrint[
 ExpressionCell[MaTeX[HoldForm[Integrate[x^2, x] = x^3/3]], 
  "EquationNumbered"]]
```